# How to manually configurate SSL Handshake in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, apache, ssl, handshake

I am setting up a server that should communicate with other trusted servers, and I am using SSL Handshake in spring boot with apache tomcat.

I managed to succeed in making 2 way SSL however if I add Root CA that did generate the certificates in the trust store it automatically trusts every child from that CA. I want it to check if that specific certificate is in the trust store not just from the same parent.

Application properties are the same for the second server just with different KeyStore and Truststore.

Application.properties

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:booker.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=pass
server.ssl.key-password=pass
server.ssl.key-alies=booker
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:bookerTrust.p12
server.ssl.trust-store-password=pass
server.ssl.trust-store-type = PKCS12
server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.port=8111
```

RestTemplate setup in main.java

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(
                new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
                    @Override
                    protected boolean hasError(HttpStatus statusCode) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        return restTemplate;
    }

    private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() throws Exception {
        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
    }

    private HttpClient httpClient() throws Exception {
        // Load our keystore and truststore containing certificates that we trust.
        SSLContext sslcontext =
                SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(trustResource.getFile(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
                        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore.getFile(), keyStorePassword.toCharArray(),
                                keyPassword.toCharArray()).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory =
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new HostCustomVerifer(trustResource,trustStorePassword,trustStoreType));
        return HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory).build();
    }
}
```

The communication in the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/server1")
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<?> getMessage(ServletRequest request) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Server1 successfully called!");
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/sdata", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getMsData() {
        try {
            String msEndpoint = https://localhost:8111/api/server2/data";
            return new ResponseEntity<String>( restTemplate.getForObject(new URI(msEndpoint), String.class), HttpStatus.OK) ;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Exception occurred.. so, returning default data", HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
    }


}
```

I expect for this scenario to fail however it succeeds:

Server1: Trusts RootCA,Server1,Server2

Server2: Trusts RootCA,Server2

Server1 starts communication with Server2 and succeeds somehow

I expect it to fail because Server2 does not trust Server1

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, however, it worked for my needs to fail communication if not trusted both ways.
I implemented javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier and made my CustomNameVerifier and did put that in SSLConnectionSocketFactory when making RestTemplate. Code that follows

Bean code should go in main (With @SpringBootApplication)

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate template() throws Exception{

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    KeyStore keyStore;
    KeyStore trustStore;
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = null;
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(keyStoreLocation.getFilename());
        InputStream inputStream = classPathResource.getInputStream();
        keyStore.load(inputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(trustStoreType);
        ClassPathResource classPathResourceTrust = new ClassPathResource(trustStoreLocation.getFilename());
        InputStream trustInput = classPathResourceTrust.getInputStream();
        trustStore.load(trustInput, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());

        javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
                .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, null).setProtocol("TLS")
                .build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory =
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                new HostCustomVerifer(trustStoreLocation,trustStorePassword,trustStoreType));

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                .setMaxConnTotal(Integer.valueOf(200))
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(Integer.valueOf(200))
                .build();

        requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(Integer.valueOf(10000));
        requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(Integer.valueOf(10000));

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occured while creating restTemplate "+exception);
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return restTemplate;
}
```

The CustomNameVerifier is as follows: (Even though you get a different error message ( it should be untrusted certificate you get for name validation failure.

```
public class HostCustomVerifer implements HostnameVerifier {

private String trustStorePassword;
private String trustResource;
private String trustType;

@Autowired
public HostCustomVerifer(@Value("${server.ssl.trust-store}") Resource trustResource,@Value("${server.ssl.trust-store-password}") String trustStorePassword,@Value("${server.ssl.trust-store-type}") String trustType) {
    this.trustStorePassword = trustStorePassword;
    this.trustResource = trustResource.getFilename();
    this.trustType = trustType;
}

@Override
public boolean verify(String hostName, SSLSession sslSession) {
    try {
        X509Certificate list[] =  (X509Certificate[]) sslSession.getPeerCertificates();
        int size = list.length;
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(trustType);
        ClassPathResource classPathResourceTrust = new ClassPathResource(trustResource);
        InputStream trustInput = classPathResourceTrust.getInputStream();
        trustStore.load(trustInput, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());  
        for (X509Certificate x509Certificate : list) {
            ArrayList<String> content = Collections.list(trustStore.aliases());
            for (String alias : content) {
                X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) trustStore.getCertificate(alias);
                boolean isSelfSigned = cert.getIssuerDN().equals(cert.getSubjectDN());
                if(cert.equals(x509Certificate) && (!isSelfSigned || size==1))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

If someone suddenly stumbles upon this thread and finds a better way you can inform me.